# Reading file from conf with Scala and Play! 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework

"file.csv" is defined in /conf folder and I'm attempting to test reading the file using Scala worksheet:

```
import javax.inject._
import play.api.Environment
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

class CountController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents,
                                 env: Environment) extends AbstractController(cc) {

   def getter() = Option(env.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("file.csv"))

}

new CountController().getter();
```

Do I need to mock `ControllerComponents` and `Environment` in order access the file ? :

```
new CountController(mock ControllerComponents , mock )Environment.getter();
```

Reading https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice does not detail mocking the environment. I',

Comment: Why mock the environment? Just construct it directly: `Environment.simple()`. BTW, if you want to retrieve a file, there's an easier way: `env.resourceAsStream("file.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

As per @cbley comment, use `Environment.simple()`